# Faulty mathematical proofs, using proportions, that assume the rationality of $\sqrt 2$

Tags: geometry

It's often said that genuine theoretical mathematics began with the discovery of the irrationality of the diagonal of a square. For instance: "The discovery of the incommensurable by the Pythagoreans was bound to cause a great sensation, the more as it would immediately be seen to throw doubt on so much of the Pythagorean proofs of theorems in geometry as rested on their (arithmetical) theory of proportion." (Heath, Manual of Greek Mathematics, 105). What is an example of a faulty proof that relies on a theory of proportion and assumes commensurability?

Comment: I don't see how the final question follows from the first remark.

Comment: Maybe this is an example of a proof using similarity and proportion. Would this be an invalid proof because it relies on proportion? https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/right_triangles_topic/pythagorean_proofs/v/pythagorean-theorem-proof-using-similarity

Comment: If you don't get an answer for several days, try reposting this on the "History of Science and Mathematics" Stack Exchange.